# Soot: Reload class after source-file changed

Tags: java, static-analysis, intellij-plugin, soot

I'm writing an IntelliJ-Plugin to analyse java-program code. Thus i use [Soot](https://github.com/Sable/soot) to write static analyses. Every time a user triggers the analyse-action of my plugin, I take the current `VirtualFile` of the current context like this:

```
FileEditorManager manager = FileEditorManager.getInstance(e.getProject());
VirtualFile files[] = manager.getSelectedFiles();
toAnalyse = files[0]; [...]
```

When I check the content of this file all changes are applied. After this I'm loading the class I want to analyse in Soot.

```
String dir =  toAnalyse.getParent().getPath() ;
Options.v().setPhaseOption("jb", "use-original-names");
Options.v().set_soot_classpath( System.getProperty("java.home")+";"+ dir);
c = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport(name);
/*no analyse c*/
```

This works perfectly for me. But now to my issue: 
If i change sth. in test instance of my plugin and trigger the same analysis again, nothing changes.

> What have i tried so far?

**I set following options**:

```
Options.v().set_dump_body( Arrays.asList("jb"));
Options.v().set_dump_cfg( Arrays.asList("jb"));
Options.v().set_allow_phantom_refs(true);
Options.v().set_whole_program(true);
```

**I also removed all classes by hand**

like this:

```
Chain<SootClass> classes = Scene.v().getClasses();
Stack<SootClass> stack = new Stack<>();
for(SootClass s : classes)
    stack.push(s);
while(!stack.empty())
    Scene.v().removeClass(stack.pop());
```

and started the program again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I solved this issue.**

```
SootClass c = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport(name);
// ...
c.setResolvingLevel(0);
G.reset();
```

`G.reset()` resets all singleton instances. 
Therefore all cached results will be overwritten by calling this action again.

```
public static Scene v() {
    return G.v().soot_Scene();
}
```

`this.instance_soot_Scene` is `null` after calling `G.reset()`.

Therefore the following code:

```
public Scene soot_Scene() {
    if(this.instance_soot_Scene == null) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if(this.instance_soot_Scene == null) {
                this.instance_soot_Scene = new Scene(this.g);
            }
        }
    }

    return this.instance_soot_Scene;
}
```

returns a new instance with an empty result cache.